# Building tmux from source

Tags: linux, tmux

I'm trying to build tmux from source (downloaded the .tar) and I've encountered some problems with dependencies.

When I run

```
./configure
```

I get this error

```
checking for LIBEVENT... no
checking for library containing event_init... no
configure: error: "libevent not found"
```

But I do have the libraries installed.

```
$ dpkg -L libevent-2.0-5 
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libevent-2.0-5
/usr/share/doc/libevent-2.0-5/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libevent-2.0-5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.0.so.5
```

I managed to solve the problem by making

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ ln -s libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9 libevent.so
```

Is the *configure* script looking specifically for *libevent.so*? If so, why is not a symlink by default on my liibevent installation?

Still, when solving that problem, another similar occurs now with *libncurses* which also I have installed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you install the "-dev" version of these libraries (i.e. "sudo apt-get install libevent-dev").  You shouldn't need to do the soft link.